# Desde un formulario cómo verificar si un correo electrónico ya ha sido registrado, usando AJAX y Javascript tanto en el cliente como en el servidor

Tags: javascript, ajax

Estoy desarrollando un formulario de registro de usuarios, los correos electrónicos deben ser únicos, quisiera que al momento de terminar de escribir el correo se haga una consulta mediante ajax a la base de datos mysql para saber si ya existe, o que al momento de darle click a submit consulte la existencia del correo en la base de datos desde luego usando ajax. Estoy desarrollando con Javascript tanto en el lado del cliente como en el servidor usando Node.js

Comment: Y cuáles son las dudas?, Considera que así como está la pregunta es seguro termine cerrada pues no hay punto claro de partida

Comment: Cómo hago la consulta a la base de datos usando ajax?